# pushing me away on the top?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

need help with my "box" that should not be able to collide with the player, i am suppose to use "intersects" and all i am getting is this bouncy mess when i try to collide. the biggest problem is that when i stand on the box it just pushes me away to the left.

```
      if (sprite.getGlobalBounds().intersects(sprite3.getGlobalBounds())) {

            if(sprite.getPosition().y > sprite3.getPosition().y) {
                sprite3.setTexture(texture4);
                player.y += 20 ;

            }
            else {
                player.y += -1;
            }


            if(sprite.getPosition().x > sprite3.getPosition().x) {
                player.x += 20;
            }
            else {
                player.x += -20;
            }
        }
        else {

            std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
        }
```

Notes: gravity is currently player.y +=1;

so what i mostly need help and want help with is why/what can i do to solve the issue with me going to the left when i stand on the box.

Comment: are your positions int or float ? Second, your if statement. If player.x > sprite.x {ok} else{  everything else } means in else branch you will end even if player.x == sprite.x

Comment: I suppose that if intersects return true, your sprites are already colliding. Based on what you want, you should try this approach: remeber player posiitons, move player, check for collisons. If you find collision, reset player posirion to stored one, else leave his new one. To solve walking upon objects, if you find collision, check if player is on the upper side of object, if he is, let him move. To make gravity, if player is no colliding with anything, just lower his y (or add, based on axis representation).

Comment: @Angen the positions are Vector2f, on your second thought, how would i change it to make it work?

Comment: @Angen i tried looking around and thinking of a way but couldn't on how finding if i am on the top side, so how would i see if player is on upper side?

Comment: You need to get position of object, its height and based on the way of drawing (if you call draw(x,y) in which section of sprite x and y are - center, left corner)  you need to calculate y for top of sprite. Then make the same with lower y of sprite for player and just ask if bottom position of player (again with respect to drawing) is higher or the same as top y of collided object.

Comment: Is there a way of calculating the minimum and maximum of a spries x and y positions?

Comment: I do not know what your sprite is. From which library came from. If it is scaled or not. Try to look into library you have it from.

Comment: its just a random squared png from the internet that i use. thank you for your time and help

Comment: I meant sprite as class object in your code. If it is part of some graphic library, look there for some functions and may be there some turorials